# Javascript map() method and arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

This probably suits other methods as well but the one i'm using at the moment is map().

How come:

```
const singleFruit = fruits.map((fruit) => fruit.toUpperCase());
console.log(singleFruit);
```

returns the array the correct way, with everything in uppercase, when:

```
const singleFruit = fruits.map((fruit) => {
fruit.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(singleFruit);
```

gives me an array but with my assigned fruits are now undefined. I can solve this by adding return before "fruit.toUpperCase();" I thought that the second code was the exact same as the first one but without the curly braces.

Thanks!

Comment: without the `{}` the return is implied - with `{}` you need to return the mapped something - [read the docs]9https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :p

Comment: Then what is the question?

Comment: this seems like you found something out and want to share it with us instead of to ask something

Comment: When you use {} then you need to use return keyword but if you just want to change element ust without {} as @JaromandaX said.